Update values in an R crosstalk filter, dependent on value selected in another filter
I am using R and crosstalk (without Shiny) to create two filters. In the below example they are a department filter and a provider filter. The functionality I'm looking for is when I select a department from the department filter, the provider filter will update to only include providers that are in the department selected in the department filter.
In the example below, when I select the Department of Cardiology, I only want the values of Dr.A, Dr.B and Dr.C in the filter for providers

library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)



data <- data.frame(
  Department = rep(c("Cardiology", "Neurology", "Pediatrics"), each = 3),
  Provider = c("Dr. A", "Dr. B", "Dr. C", "Dr. D", "Dr. E", "Dr. F", "Dr. G", "Dr. H", "Dr. I")
  ,value = seq(1:9)
)

# Create a shared data object
shared_data <- SharedData$new(data,~Department)


# Output table
bscols(
  widths = c(12),
  list(
filter_select(
    id = "department_filter",
    label = "Select Department",
    sharedData = shared_data,
    group = ~Department
    ,multiple = FALSE
  )
  ,filter_select(
    id = "provider_filter",
    label = "Select Provider",
    sharedData = shared_data,
    group = ~Provider
    ,multiple = FALSE)
  ) # close list of filters
  ,datatable(shared_data)
)


Currently, both filters do filter the table, however, when I select the department of Cardiology, all providers are still in the provider filter.
